# How to read rotation of a Microsoft Band

Tags: c#, microsoft-band

I'm trying to read the rotation of a Microsoft Band as a degree of rotation (as opposed to a velocity or an acceleration; specifically, on the x-axis). I need to measure the degree of rotation from a set point, such as the Band being face-down. Assuming the user is wearing the Band on his left hand facing in, this would mean his palm is also face-down. My goal is to be able to measure degrees of rotation from that point, and thus to be able to determine when the user rotates his hand so that his thumb is facing up or down. I was hoping the gyroscope would hold the answer to my problem but it only offers velocity and acceleration readings. So, it only seems to provide speeds of rotation which will only let me determine the rate of change and thus the total change, but that does not solve my problem unless I get the user to provide me with a starting point that I would assume to be the point at which the Band is face-down. Now, I'd rather not rely on the user if I don't have to, and the app [Bounce for Band](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/games/bounce-for-band/9nblggh3g39v) "just works" without needing calibration or anything, so it must be possible. I've hunted through the [SDK documentation](http://developer.microsoftband.com/Content/docs/Microsoft%20Band%20SDK.pdf) and found nothing. Am I missing something? Going about it in the wrong way?

Comment: Acceleration should be roughly a vector of length 1, when not in motion. And it should point down. You should be able to use this to determine the rotation angle.

Comment: I'm at work so I'll have to wait to post the code, but here is a video where I show how to do something that seems to be what you want to achieve: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FglQRjXwWp8

The video is from the beta version of the SDK btw, but I'll verify the code works on the latest version before I post.